# Attempting mount exfat partition fails with mount(2) system call failed: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, exfat

I have an exfat formatted partition (`/dev/sdc2`) with some files on it I want to keep.

Whenever I try to mount the partition I get a "Cannot allocate memory" error.

Examples of commands I've tried:

```
$ sudo mount -o ro --verbose /dev/sdc2 /run/media/phelps/Disk
mount: /run/media/phelps/Disk: mount(2) system call failed: Cannot allocate memory.
```

```
$ sudo udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdc2 --options ro
Error mounting /dev/sdc2: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error mounting /dev/sdc2 at /run/media/root/Media: mount(2) system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

It's the largest partition on a drive connected via USB.

Comment: God I'm an idiot, this is a fresh arch install, and I didn't have `exfat-utils` installed. Could you post this as an answer so I can mark this question answered?

Comment: Will do... and I've had the same issue. No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many versions of Linux do not install the exFAT file system packages by default. The [needed package](https://itsfoss.com/mount-exfat/) can be installed from Terminal. In Ubuntu (and other Debian distros):

- If "Universe" repository has not been added, enter:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe
  ```
- Update repository info:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  ```
- Install exfat-fuse package

  ```
  sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Check that you're actually using the right partition: In my case I accidentally tried to mount the extended partition itself, instead of the linux partition *inside* that.

I.e., for this disk:

```
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdg1  *         2048   1050623   1048576   512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdg2         1052670 312580095 311527426 148.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sdg5       295897088 312580095  16683008     8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdg6         1052672 295897087 294844416 140.6G 83 Linux
```

I had tried to mount /dev/sdg2 instead of /dev/sdg6 (typo, basically), which gave me the above (and not very helpful) error message. In my case, fixing  to `fdisk /dev/sdg6` fixed the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).